# 'This app could not be installed at this time' error Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, bundle-identifier

When I am trying to run my Flutter app, the build is succeeded, but when xcode tries to install this build automatically on the simulator, the following error occurs:

```
The parent bundle has the same identifier
     (com.abc.def) as sub-bundle at 
    /Users/jan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DFF35FBB-FE6C-462E-80964BFBFAF57291/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.zyu9i6/extracted/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework
```

I am already stuck for a couple of days with this error. I don't find an answer for this issue on the word wide web.

I already tried to erase all content and settings of the simulator, but that does not solve the problem. Cleaning the project is also not the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25090#issuecomment-449042782 sounds similar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the CFBundleIdentifier in this file :

```
ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
```

Add ".app" to the flutter BundleId "XXX" :

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key> <string>XXX.app</string>
```

With "XXX" your own bundle-id.

The answer is also given in this issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25090#issuecomment-449042782

Comment: For me this does not work, I keep keeping the same error message.

Comment: This solved my issue after I changed my bundle id and mistakenly removed the .app